How to disable implicit conversion arguments in a multi-param constructor?
I have a constructor with a relatively long list of arguments (say, 5 or 6), but they are all primitive types, like:
SomeClass(std::int64_t id, double param1, double param2, bool param3, std::int64_t param4, double param5)

To avoid potential wrong initialization, I wish to disable implicit conversions of the argument types. Some answers are here:
Avoiding implicit conversion in constructor. The 'explicit' keyword doesn't help here
But since the param list is long, it's tedious to cover all possible lists, as the above answer indicates.
Is there a better way to implement this?

The explicit keyword and the linked question are completely irrelevant to your question.

Can you show an example of a potential wrong initialization?

@3CxEZiVlQ if you read through the linked question you'd find a potential solution like marking every alternative as = delete but in this case it would be too many.
A potential wrong call is simple as
SomeClass(1, 2, false, 3.0, 3, 3)
Where the caller reversed the order of 3rd and 4th argument.

C++20 or earlier?

Does it work to define a deleted templated constructor with multiple template arguments?

SomeClass(1, 2, false, 3.0, 3, 3) such cases are discovered by enabling warnings and converting warnings to errors.

@3CxEZiVlQ boom you will have thousands lines of errors unless you never use 3rd party lib in your project :)

-isystem works well for 3rd party libraries. That happens very rarely that known 3rd party libraries raise warnings.

For C++20 or later:
SomeClass(std::same_as<std::int64_t> auto id,
          std::same_as<double> auto param1,
          std::same_as<double> auto param2,
          std::same_as<bool> auto param3,
          std::same_as<std::int64_t> auto param4,
          std::same_as<double> auto param5)

However, this turns the constructor into a template with all the side effect this has.
Especially that means it needs to be defined in a header. However, because there is only one valid specialization, it would also be easy to explicitly instantiate that specialization and then the definition can be in a source file as before. Alternatively this template could forward to an implementation function that uses the original non-template signature.

Thank you. Wondering if there is any pre C++20 solutions?

@AlexSuo You can do the same with SFINAE or static_asserts instead of constraints, depending on how it should behave in overload resolution.

The logic of the conclusion is wrong. Because the acceptable template args are exactly known,  an explicit template instantiation can be in a .cpp file. auto is the bigger problem.

@MSalters What is the problem with auto?

The app file needs an explicit instantiation, how do you spell that?

@MSalters I don't understand what you are getting at. Explicit instantiation is just template SomeClass::SomeClass(std::int64_t, double, double, bool, std::int64_t, double); for the definition and extern template SomeClass::SomeClass(std::int64_t, double, double, bool, std::int64_t, double); for the declaration.

It's good that you felt the code smell of the 6-params constructor !
You can use a parameterizing struct:
struct Params
{
    std::int64_t id;
    // of course give better names !
    double       param1;
    double       param2;
    bool         param3;
    std::int64_t param4;
    double       param5 = 3.14; // def value
    // can also compute values from previous members
};

struct SomeClass {
    SomeClass( const Params& p ) {...}
};

Aggregate initialization with named members is then your friend:
SomeClass x{ {.id=123, .param1=0.001, } };


Most problems with built-in data types can be solved via simple wrappers:
template<typename T>
struct exact_value{
    exact_value(T init={})
    : value{std::move(init)}
    {};

    template<typename C>
    exact_value(C&&)= delete;

    exact_value() = default;
    T value={};
};

This simple structure works the same C++11 onward, and can be used the argument type for any function:
SomeClass::SomeClass
  ( exact_value<std::int64_t> id
  , exact_value<double> param1
  , exact_value<double> param2
  , exact_value<bool> param3
  , exact_value<std::int64_t> param4
  , exact_value<double> param5 );

The downside is that it may shut down some platform dependent ABI optimizations related to function signatures. But as long as exact_value is kept for constructor argument types, the overhead can be minimal.
Other options would be to define custom initializer structures for each constructor, banning(=delete) unwanted initialization type lists, or using exact_value on std::tuple instances. But this techniques share the previously mentioned optimization downside.
A more complicated scheme is also available but it looks like voodoo(hard to read and reason) and suits large library codebases only. If the ABI optimization and C++11 compatibility are of high essence, notify me to edit.
